# split a string in dataframe column in python3

Tags: string, python-3.x, split

I have dataframe which contains two columns as given below:

```
data = [["76895","How was your day?","767392|docu73635363","How are you doing?"],["67387|876357|58745|874512","split the line"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2'])
                  col1                col2
0                 76895            How was your day?
1  767392|docu73635363  How are you doing?
2         67387|876357|58745|874512      split the line
```

I want to split the value create on | into two rows and remove "docu" and convert col1 to int. Desired output:

```
data = [["76895","How was your day?","767392","How are you doing?"],["3635363","How are you doing?"],["67387","split the line"],["876357","split the line"],["58745","split the line"],["874512","split the line"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2'])
      col1                col2
0    76895            How was your day?
1   767392  How are you doing?
2  3635363  How are you doing?
3    67387      split the line
4   876357      split the line
5    58745     split the line
5   874512      split the line
```

My try:

```
if "|" in df['col1']:

    value = int(df['col1'].split("|")[0])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of iterating over Dataframes. Instead, we could use built-in functions to manipulate the dataframe:

```
df2 = df['col1'].str.replace('docu', '').str.split('|', expand=True)
df = pd.concat([df[['col2']], df2], axis=1)
df.melt(id_vars='col2', value_name='col1').dropna().drop(columns='variable')

#                 col2      col1
#0  How are you doing?    767392
#1      split the line     67387
#2  How are you doing?  73635363
#3      split the line    876357
#5      split the line     58745
#7      split the line    874512
```

Use .str.split to extract all the ints, concatenate the new dataframe to the dataframe to what you already have, and then use melt to change to a long-form dataframe.

Comment: This code is droping columns where we don't have "|". Is it possible to put if condition ( to run your code when it finds the "|" otherwise value remains the same. I have edited my question.

Comment: It's not dropping columns that do not contain an '|', though.  In fact, when I run the code to generate your data, it throws an error. I can solve that by splitting the first sublist of 4 items into two sublists of two items. I then have your dataframe. If I then run the code above, it gives me exactly the desired output.
Could you check you have made no mistakes copying code? Both in the case of the creation of your sample dataframe, as well as in copying the suggested solution? If you're sure, please show your output and how it doesn't match the desired output.

Comment: Your code is working fine. But idk why in my real example, when I am creating dataframe where I am replacing the str part, it's not returning the rows which does not contain str part. It's giving just nan. i don't know why it is happening.

Comment: If the answer solves your question, please consider accepting it. If your question does not cover your underlying problem, either expand your question with the examples that are not working, so we can look at it, or ask a new one that covers specific problems that are new.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the list and perform the operations as shown in the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["767392|docu73635363","How are you doing?"],["67387|876357","split the line"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['col1','col2'])
#print(df)

numberList = []
col2_list = []

j = 0
for i in data:
    k = str(i[0])
    m, n = k.split(sep = '|')
    n = n.replace("docu", "")
    numberList.append(m)
    numberList.append(n)
    col2_list.append(i[1])
    col2_list.append(i[1])
#print(col2_list)
#print(numberList)

df_new = pd.DataFrame({'col1' : numberList, 'col2' : col2_list})
print(df_new)
```

Output :

```
       col1                col2
0    767392  How are you doing?
1  73635363  How are you doing?
2     67387      split the line
3    876357      split the line
```

Comment: Thanks redlegg!! But In the dataframe I might have 3 or 4 values separted by "|". Can you please edit your solution.